# Grant CREATE/ALTER permission to user

Tags: sql-server

How can I grant only `CREATE/ALTER` permission for `Procedures/Functions` only, to specific users of database (Developers). I don't want to allow them to `Create/Alter/Drop` tables or any other functionality.
Is this possible ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 - Granting permission to create stored procedures (but no other objects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226811/sql-server-2005-granting-permission-to-create-stored-procedures-but-no-other)

Answer (score 0):

you try below way

Create a  Role

```
    CREATE ROLE [user_dev] AUTHORIZATION db_securityadmin;
    GO



    GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO [user_dev];
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ALTER, EXECUTE, VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [user_dev]
```

Create user and login for test and add to the user_dev role

```
    CREATE LOGIN test WITH PASSWORD = 'dfgdfg' 
    CREATE USER test 
    EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'user_dev', @membername = 'test';
    GO
```

Then create a trigger to restrict  user_dev role from creating table and drop

```
    CREATE TRIGGER tr_db_DenyDropAlterTable
    ON DATABASE 
    FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE 
    AS 
    BEGIN 
       IF IS_MEMBER('user_dev') = 1 
       BEGIN 
           PRINT 'Not allowed'; 
           ROLLBACK TRAN; 
       END; 
    END; 
    GO
```

Comment: It is _never_ safe to allow a non-admin user to create objects in a schema owned by another user.  EG for a stored procedure the user could then create a stored procedure with EXECUTE AS OWNER and run code as schema owner.

Answer (score -1):

try this solution
open the database security from msql server management studio
[image]

then

[image]